# Create view for each library created dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-server

I don't need a debugging but rather some advice. On my project i have a list to create several client , for each client i'm creating dynamically a Library on my C# code.

Each Library have the same architecture of folder. 
Now i want to create a view who will combine/assemble all the specific folder.

For example : Client 1 / CLient 2 -> Library 1 / Library 2.

Library 1 and 2 
 - folder 1
 - folder 2

-> A view for the folder 2 for client 1 and 2 . And if client 3 is created, adding automatically the folder 2 of the client 3

So from that i would to be able to get a view who displays all folder 2 for each library (anyway how many will be creating).

I read an article about Merging document libraries using Content Query Web Part, but my problem is that the number of library will increase all the time, so i don't think that is the perfect solution.

Any advice or tutorial will be helpful.